# Simple ListView data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, binding

I'm trying to display data in a `ListView` with WPF and C#, and I'm confused by the different examples and methods I have seen. I'm looking for a fully working example similar to my program, or a list of pre-requisites to make it work. I'll be happy if I manage to display just 1 row of data from my collection. Currently, the list view displays nothing.

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Row> Rows { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<Row>();
        Rows.Add(new Row 
        {
            ID = "42",
            Category = "cat",
            CharLimit = 32,
            Text = "Bonjour"
        });
    }
}

public class Row
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int CharLimit { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Rows}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Category" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Category}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Text" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Text}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you're not setting a DataContext anywhere, which in this case should be the instance of MainWindow. I would also recommend looking into the MVVM design pattern and an MVVM framework.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check some MVVM tutorials to grasp the idea and try doing it right :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a `viewmodel` which can be set as the data context for the XAML

```
 public class WindowsViewModel
 {
    private ObservableCollection<RowViewModel> m_Rows;

    public ObservableCollection<RowViewModel> Rows
    {
        get { return m_Rows; }
        set { m_Rows = value; }
    }

    public WindowsViewModel()
    {
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<RowViewModel>();
        Rows.Add(new RowViewModel
            {
                ID = "42",
                Category = "cat",
                CharLimit = 32,
                Text = "Bonjour"
            });
    }
}
```

---

Implement the class `RowViewModel` in the below fashion:

```
 public class RowViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      public RowViewModel()
      {
      }
      private string m_ID;
      public string ID
      { 
            get
            {
                return m_ID;
            } 
            set 
            {
                m_ID = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
      }
      public string Category
      { 
            get; 
            set; 
      }

      public int CharLimit
      { 
        get; 
        set; 
      }

      public string Text 
      { 
        get;
        set;
      }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string Obj)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Obj));
        }
    }
}
```

---

In the code behind of XAML, add the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new WindowsViewModel();
        }
    }
```

---

Add the update source trigger property in the listview node:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rows, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Category" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Category}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Text" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Text}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the lengthy answer. I realize I lack a lot of knowledge on the topic so I'll read [this MVVM tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) before copy/pasting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify source otherwise, like in your case, it will look for the property in current context which by default, if nothing else is specified, will be `DataContext`. Try something like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Rows}">
```

Like that you specify that it should look for `Rows` in current `Window`

Comment: Thank you, adding a DataContext in the C# code was easy and made it work. I will also look into @Arushi-Agrawal 's solution as my ListView doesn't update when I change the properties of my Rows.