# c# ".datasource" not showing in the box

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datasource

Whenever I type the `.DataSource` it keeps having red on the bottom or having an error:

> 'ListView' does not contain a defenition for 'DataSource' and no extension method 'DataSource' accepting a first argument of type 'ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public Form4()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    lstProductsChosen.DataSource = products;
}
```

What should I do? Do I need to add reference?

Comment: What is `lstProductsChosen` ?

Comment: You should have an error message when you hover over the red line on the bottom. What is it? and what type is `lstProductsChosen` ? It seems that this type does not have a property `DataSource`

Comment: the "lstProductsChosen" is the name of my listview

Comment: are you using WinForms or WPF ? or something else?

Comment: When I hover it says "'ListView' does not contain a defenition for 'DataSource' and no extension method 'DataSource' accepting a first argument of type 'ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: It says "form", more likely it's winforms, `ListView` in winforms doesn't have such property (perhaps you create a wrong project, shouldn't it be wpf?).

Comment: Im using Windows Form

Comment: Then why do you expect [System.Windows.Forms.ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) to have `DataSource`. Are you trying some tutorial code or what?

Comment: Im trying to learn this tutorial on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99LWDWmSAqM          it's working on him

Comment: It's another control called `ListBox` (not `ListView`) in this tutorial.

Comment: OMG How idiot I am. hahaha Thanks guys love you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have a `DataSource` property.

[ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) has one. If you use a `ListBox` instead your code should work.

If you are using `WPF` you will find a [Simple ListView data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003998/simple-listview-data-binding) example behind the link.

If you are using WinForms then please check [this short and consice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2799161/5174469) by Hans Passant

Comment: My question is answered, I used listview instead of listbox haha. Thanks :)